# Why is my email validation not returning an error message I did set?

Tags: javascript

I made an email validation through Javascript. I know we can do validation through HTML, but I need to use Javascript. There are two methods that I used in this problem. First is conditioning, and second is regular expression matching. If an input email is wrong, then an error message will appear beside it, and if there's no error the form will direct to a PHP page. In my case, I input an email that I expect to get an error from, but it directs to the PHP page immediately, which is wrong.

What I want is there should be no '.' and '@' in the first and last index of the email

There should be an @ and . as per the usual email structure

There should only be 1 @ character

All characters are included.

Here is my javascript code after the html one,

```
const name = document.getElementById('name')
const lname = document.getElementById('lname')
const co = document.getElementById('co')
const email = document.getElementById('email')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const error1 = document.getElementById('error1')
const error2 = document.getElementById('error2')
const error3 = document.getElementById('error3')
const error4 = document.getElementById('error4')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  let messages = []

  var re =/^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if(!name.value.match(re)){
       messages.push('error')
        var err1="Contains number";
  }
  else{
      err1="";
  }
    if(!lname.value.match(re)){
       messages.push('error')
        var err2="Contains number";
  }

  else{
      err2="";
  }
  var t=co.value;
  //we have a problem in contact number
    if(t[4]!='-'||t[8]!='-'||t[0]!=0||t[1]!=9||t.length!=13){
        messages.push('error')
        var err3="Must follow the format";
    }

  else{
      err3="";
  }

    var m=email.value;
    var r=email.value.length;
    var atposition=email.indexOf("@"); 
    var dotposition=email.lastIndexOf("."); 
    var i, count, dot1;
    for(i=0; i<r; i++){
        if(m[i]=='@'){
            count++;
        }
        if(m[i]=='.'){
            dot1++;
        }
    }
    if(atposition<1||atposition==m[r-1]||count>1||dotposition==m[r-1]||m[0]=='.'||dot1==0||count==0){
         messages.push('error')
        err4.push('Must follow email format')
    }

  if (messages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    error1.innerText = err1
    error2.innerText = err2
    error3.innerText = err3
    error4.innerText = err4
  }
})
```

Here is my method on regular expression matching:

```
var re=/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/     
if(!email.value.match(re)){
 messages.push('error')
            err4.push('Must follow email format')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one.
var mailformat =  /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9] 
{2,4})+$/;
var email = $('#email').val();
if(!mailformat.test(email_value)){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#error-email-txt').html('Enter valid email address');
    $('#error-email').css("display",'block');
 }
```